# How to get static enum from class

Tags: grails, enums, gsp

i have an java-constraint-interface declaring some enums.

```
public interface MyClass{static enum BOOP{a,b,c,d,e,f}};
```

how can i get dynamicly the name of the 6th enum-const from the "BOOP"-enum?

```
${org.java.some.MyClass."$enumName"[5]}
```

doenst work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it by myself

```
<%=org.java.some.MyClass.class.getDeclaredClasses().find{it.simpleName=enumName}.values()[5]%>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
public interface MyClass{static enum BOOP{a,b,c,d,e,f}};

${org.java.some.MyClass.BOOP.values()[5]}    // prints f
```

Additionally, you can't get the element with index 6 due to the array is 0-based and you do not have 7 elements in your enum.

Comment: Wait, i cant code BOOP direclty, BOOP is the value of an String-Variable